# Reroute Here-map on destination change. It's a moving target

Tags: android, here-api

I am using Here Map Android SDK. Currently my app can calculate the initial route and draw it through NavigationManager. Listeners are implemented and it will recalculate/redraw when the position changes, but I have a moving target: the destination is another vehicle position I get from a web service at 30 second intervals.

What is the proper way to have the route adjusted for a change in destination?

The easy way is to create a new route with an updated destination waypoint, have it calculated, then replace the old route and its listeners with the new one. I fear this wastes computing resources and produces lag/flicker on the map during the redraw. If this is indeed the path to take, how do we minimize screen issues?

I tried just changing the coordinates of the waypoint but it has no impact. I searched for a "route waypoint change" listener, similar to a traffic or position listener but could not find any.

**Update:** Since Here confirmed a route destination cannot be updated, I clarify my request for "howto":

What objects can I reuse in the new one? Which objects must we remove from the map and/or destroy to avoid leaks?

Initial plan:

- keep handle on waypoint, original route (missing any?)
- modify the destination waypoint coordinates
- create a new route and have it calculated
- move the destination map marker to the new destination
- add new route
- remove the original route (I assume the beginning of the route is similar in most update cases, so we avoid "flicker")

Anything missing? Listeners handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here SDK does not provide such feature as of today. You can not change existing route or update its target. If you have new destination point you should calculate new route.

Comment: So then as the other part of my question says, what is the best way to approach the "refresh"? What objects can I reuse in the new route? Which objects must we remove from the map and/or destroy to avoid leaks?
My first thought would be: